# JPA select using IN

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Here is my select from the database:

```
SELECT * FROM testlogging.employees 
where
  EMPLOYEE_NO in (
    select EMPLOYEES_EMPLOYEE_NO from testlogging.test_logging
    where ID in (
      select TEST_LOGGING_ID from testlogging.test_logging_detail 
      where APPROVAL_LEVELS_ID = '4'
    )
)
```

How would i do this in JPA?

```
SELECT e FROM Employees e ???
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for the JPA `IN`syntax you would do this:

```
SELECT e FROM Employees e where e.employee_no IN :employeelist
```

as well ass

```
query.setParameter( "employeelist" , yourlist );
```

and of course build `yourlist` accordingly. If you don't really need to parameterize the inner queries, you can disregard this and just go the straight forward route.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're using the JPA Criteria metamodel queries, the IN usage goes like this

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.where(pet.get(Pet_.color).in("brown", "black"));
```

as stated at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html